# Power of multi-index

Tags: notation, index-notation

If I have $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a multi-index $\mathbf{k}=(k_1,...,k_n)$ (where each entry is a non-negative integer), then $\mathbf{x^k}$ is defined ([on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)) as
$$x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_1}...x_n^{k_n}.$$
I'm just checking I understand this correctly - so $\mathbf{x^k}$ is actually a one-dimensional element?

If so, is there a notation for the corresponding point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$(x_1^{k_1},...,x_n^{k_n})$$?

Also, does it make sense to write $\sin(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You didn't mention the domain of the elements of $k$. That is crucial information. E.g. $\mathbf{x} = (-1)$ and $\mathbf{k} = (\frac{1}{2})$ would mean $(-1)^\frac{1}{2} = i$.

Comment: @orlp edited - thanks!

Comment: @orlp does multi-index makes sense for functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reals are closed under multiplication, and are closed under exponentiation with non-negative integer exponents (as this is repeated multiplication). So yes, $\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{k}$ is in $\mathbb{R}$.

You can write $\sin(\mathbf{x})$, and I would understand it as element-wise application of the sine function to $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a notation for the corresponding $n$-dimensional point?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Not that I'm aware of. Rarely do you take different components of an $n$-dimensional point to distinct powers.